# Login form and registration form not properly displayed

Tags: javascript

I am using D7, with the help of Modal form module i am trying to display the login and registration form in a overlay effect. When the user visits /user/register or /user/login i get the overlay but not the form. I have attached a snapshot for further reference.

[image]

Where am i wrong in displaying this form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Modal forms (with ctools)](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms)

> #### Supported forms
>
> - Log in
>     (modal_forms/nojs/user/login)
> - Request new password
>     (modal_forms/nojs/user/password)
> - Create new account
>     (modal_forms/nojs/user/register)
> - Contact
>     (modal_forms/nojs/user/contact)

It is also possible to build links manually.

```
    <a class="ctools-use-modal" href="modal_forms/nojs/user/login">Modal Login</a>
    <a class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-modal-popup-small" 
href="modal_forms/nojs/user/login">Modal Login</a>
```